# SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, digital-signature

*(Sorry I know this is a complete noob question and at the risk of posting a somewhat duplicate topic. I have a basic understanding of public/private key, hashing, digital signature... I have been searching online & stack forum last couple days but cannot seem to find a satisfactory answer.)*

**Example:** 
I am surfing on open wifi and I browse to  for the 1st time. Server sends back its SSL certificate. My browser does its thing and verifies that the cert is signed by a CA that it trusts and all is well. I click around on the website. BUT!

**Question:**
Can someone actually please explain to me in a simple way how does my browser actually verify that the server certificate is legitimate? Yeah okay so on the certificate itself it says it is issued by, say "Verisign" but what is the actual cryptographic magic happens behind the scene to validate that it isn't a bogus certificate? I have heard people explain "SSL certificates are verified using the signing CA's public key" but that doesn't make sense to me. I thought public key is to encrypt data, not to decrypt data.

So confused... appreciate it if someone could enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh wait, I think I got it. Please correct me otherwise. So basically the way browser verifies the cert is by re-generating the digital signature (re-hash and re-encrypt via CA public key) and then seeing if that matches the digital signature included on the server's certificate.

Comment: actually you know what, this article clarified it for me. I did not understand the difference between encryption and signing. I thought they were the same and confused myself. Hopefully this will be helpful others :) http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/rsa-encryption-with-private-key-and-decryption-with-a-public-key

Comment: @DeerHunter thanks. That's more around how SSL works in generally. I was getting hung up on the logic behind how certificates get verified by the browser. But that's a great posting and thanks for sharing!

Comment: This question focuses on the validation of the certificate chain. While [How does SSL/TLS work?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) includes many of the aspects too it is more a general description of SSL/TLS and details of certificate validation are only a small and hard to find part of it. That's why I've reopened this question so that it is no longer marked a duplicate.

Comment: I haven't read the answers yet but I LOVE this question! I've looked up 20 sources today and no one talks about this magic. Just "certificate includes CA's public key (something that everyone has!) and that's enough". Now, let's see if anyone answers to the point!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are correct that SSL uses an asymmetric key pair.  One public and one private key is generated which also known as public key infrastructure (PKI).  The public key is what is distributed to the world, and is used to encrypt the data.  Only the private key can actually decrypt the data though. Here is an example:

> Say we both go to walmart.com and buy stuff.  Each of us get a copy of
>   Walmart's public key to sign our transaction with.  Once the
>   transaction is signed by Walmart's public key, only Walmart's private
>   key can decrypt the transaction.  If I use my copy of Walmart's public
>   key, it will **not** decrypt your transaction.  Walmart must keep
>   their private key very private and secure, else anyone who gets it can
>   decrypt transactions to Walmart.  This is why the [DigiNotar breach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar#Issuance_of_fraudulent_certificates) was such a big deal

Now that you get the idea of the private and public key pairs, it's important to know who actually issues the cert and why certs are trusted.  I'm oversimplifying this, but there are specific root certificate authorities (CA) such as Verisign who sign certs, but also sign for intermediary CA's.  This follows what is called Chain of Trust, which is a chain of systems that trust each other.  See the image linked below to get a better idea (note the root CA is at the bottom).

[image: Simple Chain of Trust]

Organizations often purchase either wildcard certs or get registered as a intermediate CA themselves who is authorized to sign for their domain alone.  This prevents Google from signing certs for Microsoft.

Because of this chain of trust, a certificate can be verified all the way to the root CA.  To show this, DigiCert (and many others) have tools to verify this trust.  DigiCert's tool is linked [here](http://www.digicert.com/help/).  I did a validation on gmail.com and when you scroll down it shows this:

[image: Certificate of Trust for Gmail]

This shows that the cert for gmail.com is issued by Google Internet Authority G2, who is in turn issued a cert from GeoTrust Global, who is in turn issued a cert from Equifax.

Now when you go to gmail.com, your browser doesn't just get a blob of a hash and goes on it's way.  No, it gets a whole host of details along with the cert:

[image: Google Public Cert Details]

These details are what your browser uses to help identify the validity of the cert.  For example, if the expiration date has passed, your browser will throw a cert error.  If all the basic details of the cert check out, it will verify all the way to the root CA, that the cert is valid.

Now that you have a better idea as to the cert details, this expanded image similar to the first one above will hopefully make more sense:

[image: Certificate Chain of Trust Expanded]

This is why your browser can verify one cert against the next, all the way to the root CA, which your browser inherently trusts.

Hope this helps you understand a bit better!

Comment: @PTW-105 So the public key decrypts the signature, beforehand does the entity sign the signature with a private key?

Comment: @PTW-105 the SSL certificate presented to the browser is in public domain and can be copied by anybody. What if it is installed by anyone else on its server? How will the browser really tie the ssl certificate to a domain?

Comment: @PTW-105 : As part of TLS handshake, browser gets "gmail.com" certificate from gmail webserver (TLS server). After that browser will identify that the intermediate CA name as "Google Internet Authority G2". Now how and from where the browser will get the cert of "Google Internet Authority G2" ? and then how it gets cert of "GeoTrust Global CA" and "Equifax" ?

Comment: @rashok: the server sends the chain cert(s) in the handshake, see The Great Bear answers at #20803 (linked above) or https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2 et pred. Although the GeoTrust-to-Equifax bridge is now obsolete; see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93081/gmail-x-509-certificate-chain and additional links there

Comment: What do you mean by **my copy of Walmart's public key** are you saying that both have a different public keys for a single private key?

Answer (score 3):

To clarify one point from the question not covered in the otherwise excellent answer by @PTW-105 (and asked in the comment there by @JVE999):

> I thought public key is to encrypt data, not to decrypt data...

The keys work both ways - what is encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted with the private *and vice versa*.  We just decide one is private and one is public, there's no conceptual difference.

So if I *encrypt* data to send to you I use your public key to encrypt it and only you can decrypt it with your private key.

<del>However, if I want to *sign* something, to prove it came from me, then I generate a hash of the message and encrypt that hash with my *private* key.  Then anyone can decrypt it with my public key and compare to the actual message hash, but they know that only I could have encrypted it, since only I have my private key.  So they know the message hash hasn't changed since I signed it, and therefore that it came from me.</del>

As per the comments, the above is not quite true.  See the [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68822/trying-to-understand-rsa-and-its-terminology) from the comment by @dave_thompson_085.  However, this isn't a "how to sign properly" tutorial, just clarifying the roles of private and public keys in encryption verses signing. The basic point in that regard is this:

- To encrypt data the external party uses a public key and only the private key holder can decrypt it.
- To sign, the private key holder uses a hash function and their private key (plus appropriate padding, etc.).  The external party can then verify the signature using the public key.  This ensures the message came from the private key holder (assuming no-one else has access to the private key).

Signing may sometimes (depending on the implementation) be done with the same key pair as encryption, just used the other way round, or it may use a distinct key pair (see [another link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/digital-certificate-deployment-using-two-certs-for-each-user/8563), also from @dave_thompson_085's comment)

Comment: Signing is not encryption; even for RSA they are similar only if you use 'textbook' RSA which is insecure and thus prohibited in real applications and in particular never used in SSL/TLS or X.509, and for other signing algorithms even less. This is covered in crypto #2123 linked above (back in 2014) also https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997 https://security.stackexchange.com/q/68822 https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11879 https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20922

Comment: Thanks.  Those were interesting reads.  I hadn't meant to go in to detail on signing algorithms, just comment on the relative roles of the two keys.  hope my edited answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other elements to cert chain verification besides signature verification.
It was already mentioned that TLS certificates for websites are checked to be sure that the domain name in the cert matches the domain name invoked by the browser.   Other things that should be checked are the Basic Constraints should be not a CA, the key usage constraints should be compatible with the type of key; RSA and ECC keys may require different key usage permissions in order to negotiate the TLS handshake correctly.  When constructing the cert chain there may be limits on the length of chains derived from a CA.  This is part of the Basic Constraints field for CAs.  There could be policy constraints but I suspect that they are not checked by browsers.  I'd be happy to hear if I am wrong about that.  Finally the status of all certs need to be checked for revocation and expiration.

Answer (score 0):

If a web site has a valid certificate, it means that a certificate authority has taken steps to verify that the web address actually belongs to that organization. When you type a URL or follow a link to a secure web site, your browser will check the certificate for the following characteristics:
the web site address matches the address on the certificate
the certificate is signed by a certificate authority (CA) that the browser recognizes as a "trusted" authority

Both the TLS and SSL protocols use what is known as an 'asymmetric' Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) system. An asymmetric system uses two 'keys' to encrypt communications, a 'public' key and a 'private' key. Anything encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted by the private key and vice-versa. When you go to a site, a website presents their public key which your browser validates and uses to encrypt the data sent (between your browser and their server) and only server/site has the private key which is able to decrypt the data.

Some info about keys:
Asymmetric encryption (or public-key cryptography) uses a separate key for encryption and decryption. Anyone can use the encryption key (public key) to encrypt a message. However, decryption keys (private keys) are secret. This way only the intended receiver can decrypt the message. The most common asymmetric encryption algorithm is RSA; however, we will discuss algorithms later in this article.

full credit to these sites:

https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/tips/ST05-010

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-cryptography.htm