# Are the public keys of root certificate and intermediate certificate contained in an SSL certificate?

Tags: tls, openssl, digital-signature

I read [this](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO18140.html), but it doesn't say if the public keys of the root and intermediaries are inside.

Comment: Neardupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chain_Of_Trust.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an X.509 certificate does not contain other public keys. And the keys alone wouldn't be very useful, anyway. In order for a client to verify a certificate, it needs the complete certificates of all intermediate CAs, not just the public keys. So web servers typically provide an entire chain of certificates.

The certificate of the root CA is *not* provided, because it must already be in the client's trust store as a trust anchor.