# Where would an HTTPS request fail if the domain erroneously resolves to the wrong IP address?

Tags: tls

I just learned that, for whatever reason, domain names can get resolved to the wrong IP address, therefore requests can hit the wrong servers. (Just some examples of erroneous domain resolutions from Server Fault: [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/631364/wrong-ip-address-registering-in-dns), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/93492/domain-pointing-to-wrong-ip-address-but-dns-records-seems-correct), [3](https://serverfault.com/questions/709694/some-dns-servers-in-the-world-giving-wrong-ip-address-for-our-domain).)

Now, if this scenario does happen and the server is configured to accept every HTTPS requests (such as in the NGINX config at the bottom), where will the process fail?

For example, if the 2 parties are `server` and `client`:

- `server`'s TLS certificate is for `domain.name` where `domain.name` resolves to the IP address of `server`.
- `client` wants to visit `https://another.org/`, but, for some unforeseen reason, it resolves to `server`'s IP address.

I have a vague idea:

1. `client` (erroneously) hits up `server` with an HTTPS request
2. This kicks off a TLS handshake

   ... which should go through because, as far as I know, [`client` will only verify the validity of `server`'s certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity), and not if the domain name `client` requested matches the domain in `server`'s certificate.
3. The first requests go through the newly established TLS connection, but all will fail in the application level as nothing makes sense.

---

The fairly standard NGINX config:

```
#############
# CATCH-ALL #
#############
server {
   listen 80 default_server; 
   server_name _;

   return 404;
}

##########################
# HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect #
##########################
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ourdomain.com;

    return 301 https://ourdomain.com$request_uri;
}

#########
# HTTPS #
#########
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/signed_cert_plus_intermediates;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/private_key;

    # ... rest of the instructions ...
}
```

Comment: How the server is authenticated is basically how the server certificate is validated - therefore marked as duplicate of such a question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The "duplicate" thread is fantastic, I was definitely missing that one, thanks! I simplified my question in the meantime to show how it differs.

Comment: I've added more duplicate questions which should solve *"as far as I know, client will only verify the validity of server's certificate, and not if the domain name client requested matches the domain in server's certificate."*. In short - the client will check the requested domain name against the certificate.

Comment: You're awesome - thank you for this detective work and, in fact, answering my question!

Comment: while i believe the essence of this question is awnsered in the other questions.. it does post a unique way of looking at the problem that (in my view) merits its own question.

@toraritte can you reformulate this question to something like: 
"in a HTTPS scenario where there is a 'catch all' server, and a client gets routed to this server for some reason. where in the process will the error happen that prevents exchange of data?"